# python Pandas - add/insert rows before or after specific sequence of column values and count number of imputed rows

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching, sequence

I have a large dataframe consisting of equipment information, ordered in sequence of the equipment name and time.

```
data = [['abc01', 3000.0, 'transac_complete', 'system', '13:10:37', 1],
       ['abc01', 100.0, 'start', 'system', '13:12:17', 2],
       ['abc01', 500.0, 'stop', 'system', '13:20:37', 3],
       ['abc01', 0.3, 'a_type_1', 'a', '13:20:37', 3],
       ['abc01', 0.2, 'a_type_2', 'a', '13:20:38', 3],
       ['abc01', 200.0, 'start', 'system', '13:23:58', 3],
       ['abc01', 1120.0, 'transac_complete', 'system', '13:42:37', 3],
       ['abc01', 505.0, 'transac_complete', 'system', '13:51:02', 3],
       ['abc01', 600.0, 'stop', 'system', '14:01:02', 4],
       ['abc01', 0.233, 'a_type_3', 'a', '14:01:03', 4],
       ['abc01', 0.244, 'b_type_1', 'b', '14:01:03', 4],
       ['abc01', 5.0, 'b_type_2', 'b', '14:01:08', 4],
       ['abc01', 0.33299999999999996, 'c_type_1', 'c', '14:01:08', 4],
       ['abc01', 1500.0, 'start', 'system', '14:26:08', 4],
       ['abc01', 24.0, 'stop', 'system', '14:26:32', 5],
       ['abc01', 500.0, 'start', 'system', '14:34:52', 5],
       ['abc01', 1000.0, 'stop', 'system', '14:51:32', 6],
       ['abc02', 9009.0, 'transac_complete', 'system', '17:21:41', 6],
       ['abc02', 66.0, 'stop', 'system', '17:22:47', 6],
       ['abc02', 100.0, 'stop', 'system', '17:24:27', 6],
       ['abc02', 599.0, 'start', 'system', '17:34:26', 6]]

columns = ['name', 'duration_sec', 'event', 'err_grp', 'timestamp', 'sequence']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columns)
```

A sample portion of my dataset looks like this:

|  | name | duration_sec | event | err_grp | timestamp | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc01 | 3000 | transac_complete | system | 13:10:37 | 1 |
| 2 | abc01 | 100 | start | system | 13:12:17 | 2 |
| 3 | abc01 | 500 | stop | system | 13:20:37 | 3 |
| 4 | abc01 | 0.3 | a_type_1 | a | 13:20:37 | 3 |
| 5 | abc01 | 0.2 | a_type_2 | a | 13:20:38 | 3 |
| 6 | abc01 | 200 | start | system | 13:23:58 | 3 |
| 7 | abc01 | 1120 | transac_complete | system | 13:42:37 | 3 |
| 8 | abc01 | 505 | transac_complete | system | 13:51:02 | 3 |
| 9 | abc01 | 600 | stop | system | 14:01:02 | 4 |
| 10 | abc01 | 0.233 | a_type_3 | a | 14:01:03 | 4 |
| 11 | abc01 | 0.244 | b_type_1 | b | 14:01:03 | 4 |
| 12 | abc01 | 5 | b_type_2 | b | 14:01:08 | 4 |
| 13 | abc01 | 0.333 | c_type_1 | c | 14:01:08 | 4 |
| 14 | abc01 | 1500 | start | system | 14:26:08 | 4 |
| 15 | abc01 | 24 | stop | system | 14:26:32 | 5 |
| 16 | abc01 | 500 | start | system | 14:34:52 | 5 |
| 17 | abc01 | 1000 | stop | system | 14:51:32 | 6 |
| 18 | abc02 | 9009 | transac_complete | system | 17:21:41 | 6 |
| 19 | abc02 | 66 | stop | system | 17:22:47 | 6 |
| 20 | abc02 | 100 | stop | system | 17:24:27 | 6 |
| 21 | abc02 | 599 | start | system | 17:34:26 | 6 |

To this, I realised that there are missing 'start' values and my first 2 values that do not fulfil the criteria as a sequence of events are single rowed events that isn't what I want.

1. how do I add/insert a new row that satisfy the condition of not having a 'start' value between 2 'stop' values (i.e. index 19-20), whether they are consecutive or not.

For consecutive values, this new 'start' row will take on the timestamp value of the 'stop' row before, and the duration value based on the difference of timestamp of the 'stop' values before and after, that should be zero.

for non-consecutive values (i.e. there are values in between 2 'stop' values, that are not 'start'), the new row should be right after the first 'stop' row and duration and time values per above.

indented df:

|  | name | duration_sec | event | err_grp | timestamp | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc01 | 3000 | transac_complete | system | 13:10:37 |  |
| 2 | abc01 | 100 | start | system | 13:12:17 |  |
| 3 | abc01 | 500 | stop | system | 13:20:37 | 1 |
| 4 | abc01 | 0.3 | a_type_1 | a | 13:20:37 | 1 |
| 5 | abc01 | 0.2 | a_type_2 | a | 13:20:38 | 1 |
| 6 | abc01 | 200 | start | system | 13:23:58 | 1 |
| 7 | abc01 | 1120 | transac_complete | system | 13:42:37 |  |
| 8 | abc01 | 505 | transac_complete | system | 13:51:02 |  |
| 9 | abc01 | 600 | stop | system | 14:01:02 | 2 |
| 10 | abc01 | 0.233 | a_type_3 | a | 14:01:03 | 2 |
| 11 | abc01 | 0.244 | b_type_1 | b | 14:01:03 | 2 |
| 12 | abc01 | 5 | b_type_2 | b | 14:01:08 | 2 |
| 13 | abc01 | 0.333 | c_type_1 | c | 14:01:08 | 2 |
| 14 | abc01 | 1500 | start | system | 14:26:08 | 2 |
| 15 | abc01 | 24 | stop | system | 14:26:32 |  |
| 16 | abc01 | 500 | start | system | 14:34:52 |  |
| 17 | abc01 | 1000 | stop | system | 14:51:32 |  |
| 18 | abc02 | 9009 | transac_complete | system | 17:21:41 |  |
| 19 | abc02 | 66 | stop | system | 17:22:47 |  |
| 20 | abc02 | 0 | start | system | 17:22:47 |  |
| 21 | abc02 | 100 | stop | system | 17:24:27 |  |
| 22 | abc02 | 599 | start | system | 17:34:26 |  |

The sequence should be changed according to only include patterns that have 'stop - eventXXX (one or more events) - start' and exclude the counts of back-to-back 'stop - start' occurrences.

2. how do i count either the number of missing 'start' values, or the number of 'start' values imputed, since they are the same thing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to loop through the list items prior to importing to pandas to check for two consecutive stop values. A simple counter would answer your second question:

```
missing_start_values = 0
for num, i in enumerate(data):
    if 'stop' in data[num-1] and 'stop' in i:
        data.insert(num, [data[num-1][0], 0, 'start', data[num-1][3], data[num-1][4]])
        missing_start_values += 1
print(missing_start_values)
```